# How to model database where different users/roles are in a project table, while all of them have to belong to user table?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, cakephp, database-design

I am trying to model a database for my current project and I came across a new problem. I have a `Project` which is supervised by `Supervisor`, `Coordinator` and `Company`. So Project table has `Supervisor.id` as foreign key and so on. There is also `Student` table which contains `Project.is` as a foreign key (because many users can do a project). This is how it is right now. What I would like to do is to have a `User` table containing a column named `type` which allows me to see what the role of that particular user is (also student). Even though the table will contain many `NULL` entries, I will have far less redundant code.

However, the main reason I want to have one `User` table is that I am using **CakePHP** and it is not easy to have different models log in. Is this possible in a nice way?

Thanks

EDIT: Maybe I should say that every one of these roles will have different permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I see three tables: `USER`, `GROUP`, and `ROLE`.

Users would be assigned to groups, and groups given roles.  I think you need three, not one.

And cardinality matters: I can see where a `USER` could be assigned to many `GROUPS`; a `GROUP` could have many `USERS`; a `ROLE` could be assigned to several `GROUPS`; and a `GROUP` could have many `ROLES`.  There are many to many JOIN tables as well:

```
USER <-> USER_GROUP <-> GROUP <-> GROUP_ROLE <-> ROLE
```

This is normalized - nothing is repeated this way.  USER, GROUP, and ROLE have primary keys.  The JOIN table primary key is a composite of the two IDs in each row.

Comment: It depends if a Supervisor has more properties than Student for example, the example does not work (having multiple NULL entries in the database is not really a good idea). What about having a User table with all common data (email, password, firstname...) and having a table for each role where you can put special data for this kind of role ? You'll be able for example to have a user associated to multiple roles.

And be careful, having project_id in the student table makes your student working on only one project...

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. Either Project or Group will need to have 3 user_ids. Which is not possible. I understand the Role part and how to link that with User. But the Group part I am still stuck.

Comment: @Chafik No Supervisor will have even less properties than Student. I think it's ok for me to have them all in 1 table. My problem is CakePHP unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how you will use your associations.

## Why not

For example: if you use relation to output data later and you sure, that you database scheme will not changed, than ... why not?  your main targets: quality of code and speed of development, so, not matter how much columns with null you will have.

## But

if you not sure in your requirements or plan to extend database scheme you can use two columns

- supervisor_model
- supervisor_id

which will store apropriate values: `Company`, `77`  (I mean that 77 it's id of come Company )

## Another approach

You can [UUID](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html#String%3a%3auuid) for you supervisor_id so,  it will be  unique among several tables and you have not  many `NULL` and extra columns.

Comment: My approach works perfectly. It's only that I HAVE TO change my approach because of CakePHP functionality.

Comment: CakePHP's AuthComponent only authenticates 1 model by default. It's not easy to have different "users" to login. Unless there's some plugin or something I don't know about.

Comment: Please, check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers  there description of how you can use several models to Auth users.  BUT ... also, you can  use simple User model there you will store type of user and related properties like student properties and supervisors properties in another talbes which will link as hasOne relation.